# android: gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I have make a gridview in which i have added images . But my problem is that it is showing very small size of gridview with only 3 images in it like in the picture and i want to show 9 images in it.

[image]s

But i want that the gridview size to be fill parent that is below photos and above bottom scroll bar.

I am using the following xml for it

```
                <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_above="@+id/LinearLayouToolbar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3">
        <ScrollView android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_width="320dp" android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">



            <GridView android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                android:columnWidth="80dp" android:verticalSpacing="20dp"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth" android:padding="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/GridView01" android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
                android:layout_gravity="fill|center" android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></GridView>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the whole layout?

Comment: don't use gridview inside scrollview.
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
and set above attribute to fillparent.

Comment: Since you set height of scrollview to 200dp hence it places gridview in within allocated height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct your scroll view width and height as:

```
  <ScrollView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
```

Otherwise remove the ScrollView, just give GridView inside the RelativeLayout.

Comment: it is quite forbidden to put a gridview in a scrollview, anyway

Answer (score 4):

You should not put a gridview (as well as a listview) inside a scrollview. In your case it seems superfluous, because the gridview will provide the scrolling for itself.